# CSS3 Gradients in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have this gradient:

```
background: #ffa13e; /* fallback */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #ff7805 10px, #ffa13e 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #ff7805 10px, #ffa13e 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #ff7805 10px, #ffa13e 100%);
background: linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #ff7805 10px, #ffa13e 100%);
```

Can IE filter actually support this type of gradient? If so, how would I implement that so it works in IE 8 9? 7 not possible?

Comment: don't sweat over it, check out [this generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome tool to generate the perfect gradient with IE support too. Use this http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/KwdwZ/1/)** is the demo for your color combination which works in IE

```
div{
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    background: #ff7805; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff7805 1%, #ffa13e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#ff7805), color-stop(100%,#ffa13e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ff7805 1%,#ffa13e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ff7805 1%,#ffa13e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ff7805 1%,#ffa13e 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ff7805 1%,#ffa13e 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff7805', endColorstr='#ffa13e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}
```

Another option to use **CSS PIE**. You can find detailed explanation for PIE in this **[LINK](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/10/css3-rounded-corners-for-ie-6-7-8.html)**

Comment: hi, this does work but my gradient cuts a corner bottom right.

Comment: @SMacFadyen I would suggest you to try CSS PIE (Link is given in my answer above), that gives support for rounded corner and gradient as well. Even border-radius is not supported in IE

Answer (score 0):

IE10 supports CSS3 gradients as standard.

For all other versions of IE (6-9), I recommend using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com) to polyfill the browser to add support for CSS3 gradients.

It is possible to use IE's proprietary `filter` style to do gradients, but really it's not worth it -- the syntax is clunky, and it has some nasty quirks and bugs (eg it breaks `border-radius` in IE9).

CSS3Pie does the gradients using VML, which means you avoid all the bugs with doing it via `filter`, and it allows you to use standard CSS syntax rather than the horrible `filter` syntax.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

I find it very useful!